# How to use backpressure with Redis streams?

Tags: redis, stream

Am I missing something, or is there no way to generate backpressure with Redis streams? If a producer is pushing data to a stream faster consumers can consume it, there's no obvious way to signal to the producer that it should stop or slow down.

I expected that there would be a blocking version of `XADD`, that would block the client until room became available in a capped stream (similar to the blocking version of `XREAD` that allows consumers to wait until data becomes available), but this doesn't seem to be the case.

How do people deal with the above scenario — signaling to a producer that it should hold off on adding more items to a stream?

I understand that some data stream systems such as Kafka do not require backpressure, but Redis doesn't appear to have a comparable solution, and it seems like this would be a relatively common problem for many Redis streams use cases.

Comment: Same question here, makes it really hard to use redis streams with SO little control over stream bounds and memory consumption

Answer (score 1):

If you have persistence (either RDB or AOF) turned on, your stream messages will be persisted, hence there's no need for backpressure.
And if you use replicas, you have another level of redudancy.
Backpressure is needed only when Redis does not have enough memory (or enough network bandwidth to the replicas) to hold the messages.
And, honestly, I have never seen this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to ?  Unless you run out of memory it is not an issue and each consumer slow and fast can read at their leisure.

Note not using consumer groups just publishing via XADD and readers read via XRANGE via position stored in a key which is closer to Kafka. Using one stream per partition.

Producer can check if the table size gets too big every 1K messages (via XLEN) to slow down if this is an issue and cant you cant throw HW at it 5 nodes with 20 Gig each is pretty easy with the streams spread across the cluster ..  Don't understand this should be easy so im probably missing something.

There is also an XADD version that trims the size of the table to ensure you don't over fill with the above but that world require some pretty extreme stuff. For us this is 2 days worth for frequent stuff which sends the latest state and 9 months for others.

Another thing dont store large messages in the stream , use a blob or separate key/ store.